# How to set Content-Type in Slim to XML?

Tags: php, xml, rss, slim

I want to output `application/xml` as the `Content-Type` for my Slim Output. Below you see my code which generates the output. All code that is commented out is unfortunately not working to output the corresponding Content-Type. Do you have any suggestions?

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use \Slim\Helper\Set;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Psr7Middlewares\Middleware\TrailingSlash;


$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->get('/{show}/feed', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args) use($app) {

    $html = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><sampletag></sampletag>';

    // $app->response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
    // $response = $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/xml');
    $response->getBody()->write($html);
    
    // return $response->withStatus(201)->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml')->getBody()->write($html);
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```php
$response = $response->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately this won't change the output when looking at the headers in network tab:
`Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: It must work like this. Otherwise another middleware is changing the content-type or it's a webserver (configuration) or firewall specific issue.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I found the error: After a closing PHP Tag there was a blank space. In that way the blank space was the first output before slim and therefore the header was set to `text/html`. Thank you for helping me to search the error outside of the slim code!

Comment: Ok good. That's why closing PHP tags should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You have commented out the line responsible for adding required headers to the response. The following works fine:

```
<?php
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use \Slim\Helper\Set;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Psr7Middlewares\Middleware\TrailingSlash;


$app = AppFactory::create();

$app->get('/{show}/feed', function(Request $request, Response $response, $args) use($app) {

    $html = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><sampletag></sampletag>';
    // Do not comment out the following line
    $response = $response->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/xml');
    $response->getBody()->write($html);
    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! Unfortunately this won't change the output when looking at the headers in network tab:
`Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Thank you for your help! I found the error: After a closing PHP Tag there was a blank space. In that way the blank space was the first output before slim and therefore the header was set to text/html. Thank you for helping me to search the error outside of the slim code!

Comment: A common practice to prevent such errors is to avoid using closing tags in php files.